# selling a ticket and replacing the sold seat with a 0

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

This is a movie ticket theatre seller program. The task is create a method that takes the price of the user's input, finds the first seat and replaces it with a 0, denoting a sold seat. I keep fiddling with it but it keeps wanting to change all instances of the price input to 0 instead of the first found.

```
public boolean getByPrice(int price) {
    boolean retVal = false; //initially false, have not found
    System.out.println("You chose to buy a ticket with price: $" + price);

    if (price == 10) {
        for (int i = 0;i<NUM_ROWS;i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<NUM_COLS; j++) {
                if (seats[i][j] == 10) {
                    retVal = true;
                    seats[i][j] = 0;
                }
                pricesAvailable[0] = pricesAvailable[0] - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if (price == 20) {
        for (int i = 0; i<NUM_ROWS;i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<NUM_COLS;j++) {
                if (seats[i][j] == 20) {
                    retVal = true;
                    seats[i][j] = 0;
                }
                pricesAvailable[1] = pricesAvailable[1] - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if (price == 30) {
        for (int i = 0; i<NUM_ROWS;i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<NUM_COLS; j++) {
                if (seats[i][j] == 30) {
                    retVal = true;
                    seats[i][j] = 0;
                }
                pricesAvailable[2] = pricesAvailable[2] - 1;
            }
        }   
    }

    if (price == 40) {
        for (int i = 0; i<NUM_ROWS;i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<NUM_COLS;j++) {
                if (seats[i][j] == 20) {
                    retVal = true;
                    seats[i][j] = 0;
                }
                pricesAvailable[3] = pricesAvailable[3] - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if (price == 50) {
        for (int i = 0; i<NUM_ROWS;i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<NUM_COLS;j++) {
                if (seats[i][j] == 50) {
                    retVal = true;
                    price = 0;
                }
                pricesAvailable[4] = pricesAvailable[4] - 1;    
            }
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Also, the other part is to implement the same type of method using location

```
public boolean getByLoc(int row, int col) {
    boolean retVal = false; //initially false
    System.out.println("You chose row: " + row + ", col: " + col);
    //************YOUR SOLUTION GOES HERE************//
    for (int i = 0;i<NUM_ROWS;i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<NUM_COLS; j++) {


        }
    }

    return retVal; //return value
}
```

I am not sure how use to make the location  method work at all

Comment: Why do you have 5 copies of the code that all do the same thing?

Comment: This is homework.  While you can get a solution on this site, you will not always get the appropriate guidance you need to learn the subject.  I suggest just going to a TA or professor if you are paying for college.  That's what you pay them for, to teach you.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop does not exit when you found a seat. You could use break like:

```
for (int i = 0; i<NUM_ROWS && !retVal; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<NUM_COLS && !retVal; j++){
        if (seats[i][j] == 10){
            retVal = true;
            seats[i][j] = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (retVal) break;
}
```

or you could add a condition to your loops like:

```
for (int i = 0; i<NUM_ROWS && !retVal; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<NUM_COLS && !retVal; j++){
        ...
    }
}
```

I would also recomend to reduce the code duplication by having the same loop in multiple ifs. How about summarizing it like this? (I assumed the pricesAvailable should only be lowerd when a seat has been found)

```
if (price == 0) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not giving away freebies"); }

for (int i = 0; i<NUM_ROWS && !retVal; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<NUM_COLS && !retVal; j++){
        if (seats[i][j] == price){
            retVal = true;
            seats[i][j] = 0;
            pricesAvailable[(price/10)-1]--;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Of couse returning inside the loops would also work if this is all you want to do in this method:

```
if (price == 0) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not giving away freebies"); }

for (int i = 0; i<NUM_ROWS; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<NUM_COLS; j++){
        if (seats[i][j] == price){
            seats[i][j] = 0;
            pricesAvailable[(price/10)-1]--;
            return true;
        }
    }
}

return false;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!  After a little brain storm session I was able to write the location method on my own. Slightly different than yours but it still gets the job done.

Comment: You're welcome. Just so you know you can indicate that this answer worked for you by accepting it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to utilise a break; somewhere if you intend to keep your code as it is.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-break-statement/

Answer (score 0):

You should break the loop as soon as the place is found. Otherwise you'll put `0` on all places that have the `price == 10`.

```
if (price == 10) {
    for (int i = 0;i<NUM_ROWS;i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<NUM_COLS; j++) {
            if (seats[i][j] == 10) {
                retVal = true;
                seats[i][j] = 0; //and here break/return.
            }
            pricesAvailable[0] = pricesAvailable[0] - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Also your basically copying the same code 5 times. **What if there were 100 different prices?** Whould you copy that code 100 times?
You should consider putting the **code that is duplicated inside a method** and the variable part (price in this example) should be an input parameter.

Moreover variable `pricesAvailable` is quite problematic. First it's not named the best way. Maybe `seatsAvailableAtPrice` would sound better? And I don't think that array is the best container for that - you should try using Map where first integer would be the price, and the second would be the number of seats left for that price.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> seatsAvailableAtPrice = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

Putting it all together you could create a method like that:

```
private void reserveFirstAvailableSeatForPrice(final int price) {
    for (int i = 0;i<NUM_ROWS;i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<NUM_COLS; j++) {
            if (seats[i][j] == price) {
                seats[i][j] = 0;
                seatsAvailableAtPrice.put(price, seatsAvailableAtPrice.get(price) - 1);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As for the second part - isn't that just checking if `i=row` and `j=col`? And if so making a reservation (setting price to `0`)?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you keep looping even after you have found the first seat with that price. The best thing here would be to use a method, like below, and return after you're done with the first one. This will solve both your refactoring problems and your incorrect values:

```
public boolean findFirst(int cost){
    for (int i = 0;i<NUM_ROWS;i++)
        for (int j = 0; j<NUM_COLS; j++)
            if (seats[i][j] == cost){
                seats[i][j] = 0;
                pricesAvailable[cost / 10 - 1] -= 1;
                return true;
            }
    return false;
}
```

Then call it from your getByPrice function like this:

```
public boolean getByPrice(int price) {
    boolean retVal = false; //initially false, have not found
    System.out.println("You chose to buy a ticket with price: $" + price);
    if (price == 10)
        retval = findFirst(10);
    //rest of the code...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the for-loop when you have found a matching seat, otherwise it will continue to check all the other seats.

You have two nested loops, but you want to break out of both. There are a few ways to do this, but as this is relatively simple code, a label will suffice. Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html.

As the comments have pointed out, this is obviously homework, so I won't post a full code listing, instead, here is a snippet:

```
rows:
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++)
{
    cols:
    for (int j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++)
    {
        if (seats[i][j] == 30)
        {
            retVal = true;
            seats[i][j] = 0;
        }
        pricesAvailable[2] = pricesAvailable[2] - 1;
        break rows;
    }
}
```

Also, please use braces around if-statements, it's just another way to introduce bugs.